# Transform column with seconds to human readable duration

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following dataframe in pyspark:

```
Name                 | Seconds

|Enviar solicitud ...| 1415

|Analizar mapa de ...| 1209|

|Modificar solicit...|  591|

|Entregar servicio...|91049|
```

I wish to convert the `seconds` column either to date or timestamp (hopefully todate), I am trying to use the following function

```
def to_date(seconds=0):
    dat = ''
    if seconds == 0:
        dat = '0'
    if (seconds / 86400) >= 1:
        day = (int(seconds / 86400))
        seconds = (seconds - 86400 * int(seconds / 86400))
        dat = f'{day}d '
    if (seconds / 3600) >= 1:
        hour = (int(seconds / 3600))
        seconds = (seconds - 3600 * int(seconds / 3600))
        dat = dat + f'{hour}hr '
    if (seconds / 60) >= 1:
        minutes = (int(seconds / 60))
        dat = dat + f'{minutes}min'   
    else:
        return '0min'
    return dat
```

But there is no easy way such as Pandas `.apply(to_date)` in pyspark, is there anyway to achieve what I am trying to do?

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
Analizar mapa de comparacion de presupuestos         1209         20min
Crear mapa de comparacion de presupuestos           12155     3hr 22min
Entregar servicios de bienes                        91049  1d 1hr 17min
```

Comment: How are you going to transform seconds to date directly? What is the expected output for your input df?

Comment: I guess what you're trying to achieve is to convert seconds into minutes, hours, etc. which is not precisely the date. That's why adding an expected output to your df would be helpful.

Comment: Added the expected output, thank you

Comment: please find my answer below - hope it's what you need.

Comment: I chose the approach which does not require installing any additional packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved without a UDF and it will much faster and scalable for big data. Try this and let me know if there is a hole in my logic.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.withColumn("Minutes", F.round((F.col("Seconds")/60),2))\
.withColumn("Hours", F.floor((F.col("Minutes")/60)))\
.withColumn("hourmin", F.floor(F.col("Minutes")-(F.col("Hours").cast("int") * 60)))\
.withColumn("Days", F.floor((F.col("Hours")/24)))\
.withColumn("Days2", F.col("Days")*24)\
.withColumn("Time", F.when((F.col("Hours")==0) &(F.col("Days")==0), F.concat(F.col("hourmin"),F.lit("min"))).when((F.col("Hours")!=0)&(F.col("Days")==0), F.concat(F.col("Hours"),F.lit("hr "),F.col("hourmin"),F.lit("min"))).when(F.col("Days")!=0, F.concat(F.col("Days"),F.lit("d "),(F.col("Hours")-F.col("Days2")),F.lit("hr "),F.col("hourmin"),F.lit("min"))))\
.drop("Minutes","Hours","hourmin","Days","Days2")\
.show()


+-----------------+-------+---------------+
|             Name|Seconds|           Time|
+-----------------+-------+---------------+
| Enviar solicitud|   1209|          20min|
| Analizar mapa de|  12155|      3hr 22min|
|Entregar servicio|  91049|   1d 1hr 17min|
|         example1|   1900|          31min|
|         example2|   2500|          41min|
|         example3|9282398|107d 10hr 26min|
+-----------------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Fits everything I was looking for: format and escalability

Comment: I believe previous answer is cleaner and also covers remaining seconds.

df.withColumn("duration", concat(
            floor(col("Seconds") / 86400), lit("d, "),
            floor(col("Seconds") % 86400 / 3600), lit("hr, "),
            floor((col("Seconds") % 86400) % 3600 / 60), lit("min, "),
            floor(((col("Seconds") % 86400) % 3600) % 60), lit("sec "),
        )).show(truncate=False)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function for that in Spark but this can be done without UDF. You can simply calculate it using division and modulo operations to get the different parts (days, hours, ...), and concatenate to get the desired formatting.

For Spark 2.4+, you can use higher-order function [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#zip_with) and [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join). First create `parts` column that contains number of days, hours, minutes and seconds from the `Seconds` column. Then zip it with the literal array of units `array('d', 'hr', 'min', 'sec')` to concatenate each part with its unit and finally join all the elements with a comma delimiter.

```
duration_parts = [(86400, 7), (3600, 24), (60, 60), (1, 60)]
exp = "zip_with(parts, array('d', 'hr', 'min', 'sec'), (x, y) -> IF(x > 0, concat(x, y), null))"

df.withColumn("parts", array(*[(floor(col("Seconds") / d)) % m for d, m in duration_parts]))\
  .withColumn("duration", array_join(expr(exp), ", "))\
  .drop("parts")\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+
#|Name                                        |Seconds|duration             |
#+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+
#|Analizar mapa de comparacion de presupuestos|1209   |20min, 9sec          |
#|Crear mapa de comparacion de presupuestos   |12155  |3hr, 22min, 35sec    |
#|Entregar servicios de bienes                |91049  |1d, 1hr, 17min, 29sec|
#+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+
```

Another way is using `concat` and add `when` expression if you don't want parts that are equal to 0:

```
df.withColumn("duration", concat(
            floor(col("Seconds") / 86400), lit("d, "),
            floor(col("Seconds") % 86400 / 3600), lit("hr, "),
            floor((col("Seconds") % 86400) % 3600 / 60), lit("min, "),
            floor(((col("Seconds") % 86400) % 3600) % 60), lit("sec "),
        )).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the output in `DD:HH:MM:SS` format.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1209), 
    (2, 12155),
    (3, 91049)
], ("ID","timeSec"))


def convert(seconds):
    days = seconds // (24 * 3600) 
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600) 
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60

    return "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" % (days, hour, minutes, seconds) 

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

apply_my_udf = udf(lambda z: convert(z), StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("timeStr", apply_my_udf(df.timeSec))

df2.show()

+---+-------+-----------+
| ID|timeSec|    timeStr|
+---+-------+-----------+
|  1|   1209|00:00:20:09|
|  2|  12155|00:03:22:35|
|  3|  91049|01:01:17:29|
+---+-------+-----------+
```